Is there any evidence that this oath of the ancient rulers was a common oath used on important occasions: "So let the gods do to me, and more also.."?
After the confrontation of Elijah with the Baal worshipers, Jezebel retorted a threat upon hearing what happened: So let the gods do to me, and more also, if I make not thy life as the life of one of them by tomorrow about this time! (1 Kings 19: 2)
In response to the stubborn refusal of King Ahab to hand over booty, Benhadad of Syria also made this oath: The gods do so unto me, and more also, if the dust of Samaria shall suffice for handfuls for all the people that follow me. (1 Kings 20:10)
Was this a saying only of that era?...or only of that region of Syria and Lebanon? Or was it also recorded by other ancient manuscripts throughout the Levant?

The same oath is also in Israel in David's time. For example Abner's threat "May God do so to Abner and more also, if I do not ... transfer the kingdom..." (2 Samuel ch3 v9) and David's promise "God do so to me and more also if I taste bread till the sun goes down" (2 Samuel ch3 v35).
My own theory is that what we have here is indirect evidence for the form of the standard covenant oath.
Firstly, we gather from Genesis ch15 vv7-17 and again from Jeremiah ch34 vv18-20 that one form of covenant making ceremony involved cutting sacrificial animals in half and passing between the two halves.
Secondly, that Jeremiah quotation includes God's warning to those who have already broken that covenant that he will "make them like the calf which they cut in two and passed between the two parts" (RSV).
I premise that this warning carries out a threat which they had already laid upon themselves as part of the covenant ceremony. In effect, he is invoking the "penalty clause" of the contract.
That is to say, I would reconstruct the standard covenant oath as "May God do the same to me [as we have already done to these animals] and more also if I break the terms of this covenant."
From the mouths of people like Benhadad and Abner we may get a profane version of this oath, an equivalent of the modern English "I'll be damned if I don't get my revenge!"

+1. Good answer.
